What are the automorphisms of finite commutative groups？
What are the automorphisms of finite commutative groups？Is there a relatively complete conclusion? Although it can be decomposed into the direct product of cyclic groups, this question still seems very difficult.

@ADL please define what is research level.  Thanks & good luck :)

Yes, there is a complete answer to this question. See, for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605185.
